# ¿Cómo puede iterar acumulativa o escalonadamente en Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo un *DataFrame* con varias columnas y miles de filas, con datos como este ejemplo:

```
import io

   import pandas as pd

   data = io.StringIO("""\n               
    index     id    time    Iris    mmL    mmR
      0      1059    1        2.2    12    12
      1      1059    2        2.25   12    11
      2      1059    3        2.25   10    12
      3      1059    4        2.4    14    15
      4      1059    5        2.39   14    14
      5      5287    1        1.97   17    16
      6      5287    2        1.98   18    17
      7      5287    3        2.04   17    18
      8      5287    4        2.01   16    16
      9      5287    5        2.15   15    17
      """)

df = pd.read_csv(data, sep="\s+", engine="python")
```

Dupliqué la columna `id` porque en mi *DataFrame* original a veces hay `id` repetidos pero que hacen referencia a un subgrupo de datos diferentes.

```
df['code']=df['id']
```

Y se ve como esto:

```
>>> df
```

```
index    id     time    Iris    mmL mmR code                
   0    1059    1       2.20    12  12  1059
   1    1059    2       2.25    12  11  1059
   2    1059    3       2.25    10  12  1059
   3    1059    4       2.40    14  15  1059
   4    1059    5       2.39    14  14  1059
   5    5287    1       1.97    17  16  5287
   6    5287    2       1.98    18  17  5287
   7    5287    3       2.04    17  18  5287
   8    5287    4       2.01    16  16  5287
   9    5287    5       2.15    15  17  5287
```

Entonces, decidí agruparlos por el `id` y el `time`, por medio de una tabla dinámica para que los `id` que se repiten pero que pertenecen a subgrupos diferentes no se mezclen:

```
pivot=df.pivot_table(values=['code', 'Iris', 'mmL', 'mmR'], index=['id', 'time'])
```

Este es el resultado:

```
            Iris    code    mmL mmR
id    time              
1059    1   2.20    1059    12  12
        2   2.25    1059    12  11
        3   2.25    1059    10  12
        4   2.40    1059    14  15
        5   2.39    1059    14  14
5287    1   1.97    5287    17  16
        2   1.98    5287    18  17
        3   2.04    5287    17  18
        4   2.01    5287    16  16
        5   2.15    5287    15  17
```

Ahora bien, sé por las recomendaciones en otras preguntas de esta comunidad, que no se debe iterar en pandas, sin embargo, lo que quiero hacer es lo siguiente: si el `code` es el mismo se debe ir calculando el promedio de los valores acumulativamente, pero he intentado pensar en un bucle `for` o `while`, pero no he podido hacerlo.

En definitiva lo que quiero es lo siguiente:

```
            Iris    code    mmL mmR  mediaIris  media_mmL  media_mmR
id    time              
1059    1   2.20    1059    12  12      2.200      12.000    12.000
        2   2.25    1059    12  11      2.225      12.000    11.500
        3   2.25    1059    10  12      2.233      11.333    11.667
        4   2.40    1059    14  15      2.275      12.000    12.500
        5   2.39    1059    14  14      2.298      12.400    12.800
5287    1   1.97    5287    17  16      1.970      17.000    16.000
        2   1.98    5287    18  17      1.975      17.500    16.500
        3   2.04    5287    17  18      1.997      17.333    17.000
        4   2.01    5287    16  16      2.000      17.000    16.750
        5   2.15    5287    15  17      2.030      16.600    16.800
```

Comment: +1 por una pregunta muy bien planteada, clara, con mínimo ejemplo reproducible y hasta con datos de prueba.

Comment: @abulafia gracias amigo, hoy alguien por fin podrá conciliar el sueño :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¡Mira mamá, sin bucles! :-)

```
aux = pivot.groupby(level=0).expanding().mean().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
pivot["mediaIris"] = aux.Iris
pivot["media_mmL"] = aux.mmL
pivot["media_mmR"] = aux.mmR
```

(`pivot` es el dataframe que tú creaste usando `df.pivot_table()`)

Resultado:

```
           Iris  code  mmL  mmR  mediaIris  media_mmL  media_mmR
id   time                                                       
1059 1     2.20  1059   12   12   2.200000  12.000000  12.000000
     2     2.25  1059   12   11   2.225000  12.000000  11.500000
     3     2.25  1059   10   12   2.233333  11.333333  11.666667
     4     2.40  1059   14   15   2.275000  12.000000  12.500000
     5     2.39  1059   14   14   2.298000  12.400000  12.800000
5287 1     1.97  5287   17   16   1.970000  17.000000  16.000000
     2     1.98  5287   18   17   1.975000  17.500000  16.500000
     3     2.04  5287   17   18   1.996667  17.333333  17.000000
     4     2.01  5287   16   16   2.000000  17.000000  16.750000
     5     2.15  5287   15   17   2.030000  16.600000  16.800000
```

### Explicación

En el fondo lo que buscas es la "expanding media" dentro de cada id. Pero para llegar a ello hay que dar algunas vueltas:

- `pivot.groupby(level=0)` agrupa tu dataframe `pivot` en grupos, según el primer nivel del índice. Cada grupo es por tanto un dataframe que contiene los tiempos 1 a 5 de ese id.
- Añadimos `.expanding().mean()` calcula lo que se buscaba, la media "acumulativa" dentro de cada grupo. El truco aquí es usar `expanding()`. Sin él te calcularía simplemente el promedio de cada grupo, dando como resultado un número, en vez de una serie de ellos con las medias acumulativas.

  Este sería el resultado del código hasta este momento:

  ```
  >>> pivot.groupby(level=0).expanding().mean()

                      Iris    code        mmL        mmR
  id   id   time                                        
  1059 1059 1     2.200000  1059.0  12.000000  12.000000
            2     2.225000  1059.0  12.000000  11.500000
            3     2.233333  1059.0  11.333333  11.666667
            4     2.275000  1059.0  12.000000  12.500000
            5     2.298000  1059.0  12.400000  12.800000
  5287 5287 1     1.970000  5287.0  17.000000  16.000000
            2     1.975000  5287.0  17.500000  16.500000
            3     1.996667  5287.0  17.333333  17.000000
            4     2.000000  5287.0  17.000000  16.750000
            5     2.030000  5287.0  16.600000  16.800000
  ```

  Nos ha calculado también la media acumulativa de la columna "code", pero no importa ya que luego no la usaremos. Como ves ya sale casi lo que se quería, pero en el índice se ha duplicado la columna "id". Esto es un efecto secundario del uso de `expanding()` que no acabo de comprender. Pero para eliminar ese problema:
- Añadimos `.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)` que elimina el primer nivel del índice (el campo "id" que se nos duplicó). De este modo tenemos ya un dataframe con los resultados buscados:

  ```
  >>> pivot.groupby(level=0).expanding().mean().reset_index(level=0, drop=True)

              Iris    code        mmL        mmR
  id   time                                        
  1059 1     2.200000  1059.0  12.000000  12.000000
       2     2.225000  1059.0  12.000000  11.500000
       3     2.233333  1059.0  11.333333  11.666667
       4     2.275000  1059.0  12.000000  12.500000
       5     2.298000  1059.0  12.400000  12.800000
  5287 1     1.970000  5287.0  17.000000  16.000000
       2     1.975000  5287.0  17.500000  16.500000
       3     1.996667  5287.0  17.333333  17.000000
       4     2.000000  5287.0  17.000000  16.750000
       5     2.030000  5287.0  16.600000  16.800000
  ```

Una vez tenemos lo que buscábamos en este dataframe `aux`, asignarlo a las columnas adecuadas de `pivot` es trivial:

```
pivot["mediaIris"] = aux.Iris
pivot["media_mmL"] = aux.mmL
pivot["media_mmR"] = aux.mmR
```